# How to make jQuery or javascript slide that displays three images at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been looking at slides using jQuery. now I have a lot of questions about doing different types of slides. I want to know how I can create a slide for 20 images with three photos being displayed at a time which are the current images selection, the next and previous image. The slide also contains buttons as seen below[image]

Comment: If your looking.. keep looking and you can also find how to make jQuery / JavaScript and ES6 sliders on the net.. keep looking and learn from tutorials..

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery [flexslider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) you can achieve this easily.

[WorkingFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/amravcdg/)

**Html**

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="reviews-slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
  $('#reviews-slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    itemWidth: 200,
    itemMargin: 1,
    minItems: 3,
    maxItems: 20,
    move: 0,
  });
```